# Android Camera API crashes when returning to fragment

Tags: php, android, camera, crash

So I'm having a bit of trouble with my Android application. The aim of this code is that the user will be able to click a button and take a picture, this picture will be displayed in an ImageView and then be uploaded to a server with a php script.

Running this on my device allows the user to take the picture but then fails to return to the app, as if the onActivityResult is not invoked. I have also tried running a second activity within the app and that too has the same consequence.

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    private Button mTakePhoto;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private static final String TAG = "upload";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

        mTakePhoto = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.take_photo);
        mImageView = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        mTakePhoto.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
        case R.id.take_photo:
            takePhoto();
            break;
        }
    }

    private void takePhoto() {
        dispatchTakePictureIntent();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + this);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            setPic();
        }
    }

    private void sendPhoto(Bitmap bitmap) throws Exception {
        new UploadTask().execute(bitmap);
    }

    private class UploadTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps) {
            if (bitmaps[0] == null)
                return null;

            Bitmap bitmap = bitmaps[0];
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, stream); // convert Bitmap to ByteArrayOutputStream
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray()); // convert ByteArrayOutputStream to ByteArrayInputStream

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            try {
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://link-to-serverupload-phpscript"); // server

                Random r = new Random();
                int intRandom = r.nextInt(9999);
                String prefix = "SSImg_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "_" + intRandom + ".jpg";

                MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
                reqEntity.addPart("myFile",prefix, in);
                httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

                Log.i(TAG, "request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
                HttpResponse response = null;
                try {
                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    if (response != null)
                        Log.i(TAG, "response " + response.getStatusLine().toString());
                } finally {

                }
            } finally {

            }

            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (stream != null) {
                try {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume: " + this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    }

    String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
    File photoFile = null;

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        String storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/picupload";
        File dir = new File(storageDir);
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdir();

        File image = new File(storageDir + "/" + imageFileName + ".jpg");

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        Log.i(TAG, "photo path = " + mCurrentPhotoPath);
        return image;
    }

    private void setPic() {
        // Get the dimensions of the View
        int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
        int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

        // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        // Determine how much to scale down the image
        int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

        // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor << 1;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);

        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
        //Rotating Bitmap
        Bitmap rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mtx, true);

        if (rotatedBMP != bitmap)
            bitmap.recycle();

        mImageView.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);

        try {
            sendPhoto(rotatedBMP);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

After researching the issue, I have implemented the `super.onActivityResult()` method but with no success.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It could be just the importing of fragments instead of the app.v4.fragment use the other one if no luck print the logcat and show here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. The reason my app was not working with the fragments was that for some reason in my Manifest I was calling `Android:noHistory="true"'

After removing that the app functions perfectly!